# What is the best way to run some method only on FIRST startup of Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I need to run some methods only once, when application starts **for the first time**. Is there any basic way to do this in Spring java/kotlin?

UPD:
For the first time means that i have new app that should run some methods on startup, but when i restart this app, i don't want it to run this method again

Comment: what does "for the first time" even mean? like first time ever in history? or in a given server? does a new version of the app count?

Comment: you'll need some to store a flag somewhere... Running on startup can be done using e.g. PostConstruct

Comment: personally I'd implement a separate app for the first time, and not confuse it with spring app

Comment: Running something only once suggests some form of persistence. You don't likely even need a flag, just try to detect *the effects of the first run being present* and don't run the rest of the setup method if they are. Also, if the changes are DB-related, I'd suggest a DB migration tool like Flyway or Liquibase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use the ApplicationReadyEvent. According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.html), the ApplicationReadyEvent is an:

> Event published as late as conceivably possible to indicate that the application is ready to service requests.

So, you could implement your own ApplicationListener listening for the ApplicationReadyEvent and run your code only when the application is ready, for example:

```
@Component
@Order(0)
class CustomApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
      // run your code
  }

}
```

Comment: how would this prevent running if app is restarted multiple times?

Comment: It won't. The question was updated while I was typing my answer. However, multiple restarts could be handled in the onApplicationEvent method, e.g store a flag on the first run (on a file, db, etc) and check this flag on the other runs.

Comment: Yeah, i think flag is the only option to do that, so ApplicationListener is ok, thanks

Comment: @Pixel so why have you approved this answer and not the answer suggesting a flag to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your method with @PostConstruct (make sure you've made spring bean).

At the beginning of that method you can check if file "dummy.txt" exists in project directory if not proceed with method. At the end create file "dummy.txt".

You can also add property while starting java process first time like this:

```
java -DfirstTime=true -jar myjar.jar
```

Make `firstTime` false by default